# JAVA XWPFDocument script gives java.lang.Error

Tags: java

I am sorry, I am absolutely new to JAVA and no (until now) nothing about JAVA, and only little to coding. I wanted to learn simple document creation with the XWPFDocument Library. I got a sample code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-to-write-a-paragraph-in-a-word-document/ but the code does not work.
I am also sorry for not being able to format the code as a code. I made spaces with my hand, but not everywhere. I know it's horrible, but I don't know how to do to properly.  A have a brand new Mac and a microsoft keyboard which drives me crazy + I also do not know how to do it the advice strg + k

I get the error:

```
    at GFG.main(docgen_V0.1.java:17)
```

js@MacBook-Pro-von-Jonathan ~ %  /usr/bin/env /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --enable-preview -XX:+Show
CodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -cp /private/var/folders/fq/f_v1db_d17qc749gnnmrbch00000gn/T/vscodesws_2d1b0/jdt_ws/jdt.ls-java-project/bin G
FG
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
XWPFDocument cannot be resolved to a type
XWPFDocument cannot be resolved to a type
XWPFParagraph cannot be resolved to a type
XWPFRun cannot be resolved to a type
XWPFRun cannot be resolved to a type
XWPFRun cannot be resolved to a type

The Code is:

```
    public class docgen_V0.2 {
        // Java Programming to Write a paragraph in a Word Document

    // Importing required packages
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
    import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

    public class GFG {

        // Main driver method
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {

            // Create a blank document
            XWPFDocument xwpfdocument = new XWPFDocument();

            // Create a blank file at C:
            File file = new File("/Users/Shared/Arbeit/Codes/Speachdoc/addParagraph.docx");

            // Create a file output stream connection
            FileOutputStream ostream
                = new FileOutputStream(file);

            /* Create a new paragraph using the document */

            // CreateParagraph() method is used
            // to instantiate a new paragraph
            XWPFParagraph para = xwpfdocument.createParagraph();

            // CreateRun method appends a new run to the
            // paragraph created
            XWPFRun xwpfrun = para.createRun();

            // SetText sets the text to the run
            // created using XWPF run
            xwpfrun.setText(
                "Geeks for Geeks is a computer science portal which aims "
                + "to provide all in one platform for learning and "
                + "practicing.We can learn multiple programming languages here. ");

            // Write content set using XWPF classes available
            xwpfdocument.write(ostream);

            // Close connection
            ostream.close();
    }
    }

    }
```

I just tried to run it. I expect to create a document with a little paragraph that says:
" Geeks for Geeks is a computer science portal which aims to provide all in one platform for learning and practicing.We can learn multiple programming languages here."

Comment: Ultimately you're running into an issue that would cross programming language boundaries - you are dependent on another library.  I'd strongly encourage you to start with an IDE such as [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) that can help you with errors in your code and help you with dependencies.  For Java, you'll need to somehow get the "jar" file that contains the POI libraries.  This will get you started.  From there you'll need a build environment tool but you'll get there.

Comment: I programmed already a bit in python, and also came to the thought, that I need the proper libraries. I have VS Code, but it's not so easy to set it up. But I'll manage somehow. Thanks for your help.